# Do XeTeX and LuaTeX always use Unicode?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, tex-core, luatex, unicode

I am writing some functions to manipulate strings. A typical way to produce a character with a given character code is the `\lowercase` primitive. The following code produces a character with code 234, and displays it to the terminal.

```
\lccode`*=234
\lowercase{\message{*}}
```

If I replace `234` by `345` above, then pdfTeX raises an error: `Invalid code (345), should be in the range 0..255.` On the other hand, LuaTeX and XeTeX are happy up to `1114111`, as expected from a Unicode-compliant engine.

Now, I want my macros to be as robust as possible. Is it *always* true that the maximum lccode is 255 in pdfTeX and 1114111 in LuaTeX and XeTeX? Or can a user prevent in any way the engine from using the full range, hence confusing my macros?

Comment: AFAIK, XeTeX and LuaTeX can use a different *input* encoding. But the two engines both always use Unicode internally.

Comment: I'd say yes. Why shouldn't it be true? As Leo Liu remarks, there's `\XeTeXinputencoding` that does a conversion of the input into Unicode, but that's all; when a character enters XeTeX it's changed into its Unicode correspondent in a way similar to the `^^` and `^^^^` conventions: the mouth will act on the changed character and so `\lowercase` and `\uppercase` need the whole set.

Comment: @LeoLiu: that's also my thought, but could there be some command-line switch? (I'm thinking of the difference between `pdftex` and `pdfetex`, where the former disables some commands.)

Comment: I've no idea. You'd better ask the maintainers.

Comment: The luatex manual says quite clearly that `\char now accepts values between 0 and 1114111` and extends this statement to the other similar commands like `\lccode`. As far as I know this is true in xetex too. (But the etex extension can be disabled in both engines).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: if possible, also clarify on whether disabling the etex extension changes the maximum `\char` or not (I believe not).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LuaTeX manual says quite clearly that `\char` now accepts values between 0 and 1114111 and extends this statement to the other similar commands like `\lccode`. As far as I know this is true in XeTeX too. And IMHO a command line to change this seems rather senseless.

But the eTeX extension can be disabled in both engines. Or more precisely: XeTeX has a command line option to *enable* the eTeX extension (which is used by default by all TeX Systems) and LuaTeX has a similar feature. So it is possible to build a format manually which doesn't use them. But this affects only the eTeX relevant commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of 'old' documents and I didn't want to change to utf-8.

I used the following code in my preamble to use the 'old' encoding:

```
\ifxetex
  \XeTeXinputencoding "cp1252" % actual document
  \XeTeXdefaultencoding "cp1252" % sequent documents (\input)
\fi    
\usepackage[latin1]{luainputenc}
```

I don't know if this will make problems with your code - but you can try it.

Comment: -1. I'm sure that Bruno knows that input encodings can be changed. But the question is about internal encodings. `\XeTeXinputencoding` does nothing with `\lccode`. Moreover, `\XeTeXdefaultencoding "cp1252"` is dangerous because LaTeX itself writes some auxiliary files and they're always UTF-8 files. BTW, UTF-8 is compatible with Latin-1 encoding, but Latin-1 and cp1252 are different, cp1252 is superset of latin-1.

Comment: @LeoLiu: you were maybe a little bit harsh. I indeed knew/expected that XeTeX would be able to somehow change input encodings, and here knut gives me a precise example of use. So the answer is off topic, but still useful for me.

Comment: @Leo - A quibble, I'm not sure what you wrote is what you meant to write: latin-1 is not compatible with utf-8.  For example, the hex-encoded two-byte string C3 B6 corresponds to the character ö in utf-8 and the two characters Ã¶ in latin-1.

Comment: @Charles: I was wrong. ASCII is compatible with UTF-8. Say, UTF-8 is superset of ASCII.